# How can I program a macro that will do the clicking for me in a web game?

Tags: python, macros

I'm currently playing Mr. Mine and I'm lazy to click 'sell' every 1~2 minutes.

I could use a mouse macro program that I can make the computer to do the clicking for me but this sounds like an inelegant method.

I was thinking about some way I could make a code that will hack into the web browser with the web game on and somehow send some kind of 'request' to the server that will sell the minerals.

I mean, after all, clicking it by hand eventually will send some request to the server so why not do this sending through a preprogrammed code?

I know my question is broad, so let me ask a few questions that will give me a lead to start on my project.

1. What to I need to learn to understand the 'sending request' part?
2. Is there anyone or any script that has already done what I want to do?

I'd like to take a look at the source code. (it's okay even if its not Mr.Mine. any other web game would also be of help)

Also, I'm currently interested in python so if there's any example in python, I'd be really thankful.

---

### update: "I've solved the problem"

I'm just writing how I solved the problem just in case some other folk who just started Mr.Mine faces the same laziness that I did.

As it turns out, Mr.Mine doesn't actually exchange packets with its server. It only uses internet connection for initial loading of images and all that.(I think it is..)

If you right click on the Mr.Mine web page and view the html code of it, you'll find that its full of javascripts.

After roughly reading through these javascripts, my theory that this game doesn't rely much on packet data became more persuasive.

Anyway that's why I approached my problem at a javascript perspective and I finally got a solution

What you need to do is utilize chrome's developer tools.(I'm a chrome user)

You can access to this tool also simply by: from the mr.mine web page, right click anywhere -> click the very last button. Then you'll see some panel popping up at the bottom of the screen.

this tool enables you to fiddle with the html code or javascript in it.

I'm not good at this either since this is my first time actually using it for a practical purpose. 
I just managed to scrape enough knowledge about this by googling to satisfy my needs.

In this new panel, at the top menubar, there's the 'Console' tab on the very right.
Click this and you'll see a command console.
This is where you can execute java commands within the javascript of the webpage.

Well from here, its strictly 'Mr.Mine' related.

From my previous rough reading of the javascript, I found that the sell buttons have been given the ID such as 'SB2', 'SB3', 'SB4', and so on.

So what I did was just type

```
    setInterval(document.getElementById("SB2").onclick, 300);
```

at the command line and pressed enter.
this command will automatically press the SB2 button(which corresponds to 'Coal') every 0.3 seconds.

*Caution: you must have the 'selling' page opened when this code is executed. I found out that if the 'sell' page is not opened, the code doesn't work.

*Caution2: another funny thing is, even within the 'sell' page, if you transfer to the 'sell isotope' page, it will automatically sell Uranium 238. That's because the SB2 button corresponds to Uranium 238 in 'sell isotope' tab. So be careful!

*Caution3: if you do this, an error popup will constantly come up. I just enabled the 'never show this popup' checkbox and after that it just worked fine. But one side effect: the usual popup that came up after pressing the 'save' button no longer appeared... but its worth the sacrifice isn't it?

anyway, if you want to automatically sell other ores, all you have to do is type similar codes like:

```
    setInterval(document.getElementById("SB3").onclick, 300);
    setInterval(document.getElementById("SB4").onclick, 300);
```

... etc.

see that just changing the number after "SB" corresponds to the next ore(isotope) in the list.

Well, thanks for reading this much, and I hope other Mr.Mine users can be creative and do more through this technique.

Comment: I am botting various browser games. The basic idea is not to simulate the mouse clicks, but the data flow. Examine how login works and what is sent to the server when you sell (or do any other interaction). Emulate these HTTP-requests.

Comment: i think it's beyond http-requests, you might have to deal with flash too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a packet capturing tool such as [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/%E2%80%8E). With that figure out the format and data that the game sends to the server.

Once your know the structure you could write your script to intercept your game traffic, add the needed parameters and send requests on a timed basis. (This is all assuming it does encrypt its network traffic, in which case this may be a bit more difficult)

You may find some additional information with [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=python%20packet%20capture) search.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you can use http://www.sikuli.org/. i have successfully used this to do a fairly complicated automation routine for eve online.